# OpenXML to HTML - Table Row Height Issue

Tags: html, converters, openxml

I’m using the OpenXML HTML converter in the following process:

1. Download a Google Doc in docx format
2. Convert docx to html

I have an issue with the Table row height. When I download the Google Doc into docx format the table row heights are maintained.  However when I convert the docx to HTML the table row heights are not maintained.  According to the OpenXML spec there should be a trHeight property that controls the table row height.  I cannot find any trHeight properties in the docx files XML.  Something is causing the docx file to maintain the same table row height as the original Google Doc.  However this is not flowing through to the HTML.  What is controlling the row height in the docx, given the absence of the trHeight property?

Here are links to the relevant files:

1. [Original Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N1Oq1t7R8tRYeerORzA0iV728AzrQoTo2lB5rdqGHgk/edit?usp=sharing)
2. [Exported Word Document](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35568589/Internal_Memo_JiKcrFCMa0qwI3bxdruSug.docx)
3. [Converted HTML](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35568589/Internal_Memo_JiKcrFCMa0qwI3bxdruSug.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think we'd need to see an example, or have more detailed description of what you're seeing. Barring other factors like trHeight, Word will make the row height big enough to accommodate the tallest cell in the row when its wrapped text is taken into account.

Is it getting cut off in HTML so cell text is hidden at the bottom? Or just blank space at the bottom is being trimmed? If the latter, blank paragraphs being used for spacing might be trimmed out of the HTML.